# large Arithmetic operations are taking more time in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Spark `3.4.0`,
when applying the following query to a dataset, it takes more time. While debugging the Spark code, it appears to be looping inside the `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.checkInputDataTypes` method. I believe it's resolving the expression, but it hasn't completed even after an hour

**QUERY ::**

```
SELECT `TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`__zsid`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`__zsitime`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c37`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c35`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c0`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c1`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c2`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c3`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c4`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c5`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c6`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c7`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c8`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c14`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c16`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c28`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c35`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c48`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c49`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c50`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c51`,
`TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`.`_c399`,
((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c0,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c35,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c1,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c37,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c0,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c1,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c35,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c1,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c35,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c0,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c35,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c1,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c37,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c0,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c1,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c35,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c1,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c35,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG)))+((1/16)*(CAST(EXTRACT_NUMBER(_c2,'{"name":"number","baseType":"number","format":{"disable":false,"format":"##0"},"hasUnits":false,"hasConstraints":false,"isMandatory":false}') AS LONG))) AS `_c402` 
FROM `TEMP2024021211370892970659720237864687`
```

**EXTRACT_NUMBER = UDF function**

Please help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Please add your input data and expected data ?